# How to read/write realm database created in react native via native/turbo/expo modules?

Tags: realm, realm-java, realm-js

Should I use `realmjs` for `react native`, `realm-kotlin` for `android` and `realm-swift` for `iOS`?

Is there any documentation giving guidance on how to achieve this?

I found it really hard to do it I don't know where to start it.

Please help thank you.